# <h:messages> on multiple IDs or parent id

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I was just wondering if there is a way to display multiple errors/warnings with `<h:message>` oder `<h:messages>`.

For example, take a PanelGroup with various inputs:

```
<h:panelGroup id="pG">
    <p:input id="in1">[...]</p:input>
    <p:input id="in2">[...]</p:input>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now i could use `<h:message for="in1" style="color:red"/>` to display errors in the input-area. But, is there a way to display all messages concerning the panel-group? Something like this: `<h:messages for="pG" style="color:red"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method to get list of all the validation messages for its child component,

```
<ui:repeat var="message" value="#{applicationScopedBeanUtil.getMessages(mybean.pG)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{message.summary}" />   
</ui:repeat>

<h:panelGroup id="pG" binding="#{mybean.pG}">  
    <p:input id="in1">[...]</p:input>
    <p:input id="in2">[...]</p:input>
</h:panelGroup>
```

You can add this method to your utility class,

```
 private List<FacesMessage> getMessages(UIComponent component) {
        List<FacesMessage> messages =  new ArrayList<FacesMessage>();
        Iterator<UIComponent> children = component.getFacetsAndChildren();

        if (children != null) {
            while (children.hasNext()) {
               messages.addAll(FacesContext.getMessages(children.next().getClientId()));
            }
        }
      return messages;
    }
```

Comment: Well, i never thought about doing this in a Bean. Thank you, great idea!